# Which driver is handling my IOCTL

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am opening a socket like this: 
`skfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );`
and then doing an ioctl on skfd like:  `ioctl(skfd, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr)`
I want to know which driver is handling this IOCTL in my kernel.
I know that had it been a character driver, I could have looked up for the major number of the file I am opening and then do a `cat /proc/devices` to find which driver is registered with that major number.
Must be some similar way here.

Comment: I suggest to grep your kernel. http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=SIOCETHTOOL

Comment: The files which show up on grep in the drivers folder (didn't bother doing a grep in others ofcourse) are the files not used by my configuration, e.g. drivers for devices I am not using, how do i know that? I see that the files have not been compiled. I am using kernel 2.6.32, actually that is the one which is being used in this system for some years. So does that mean that in this kernel I won't be able to use ethtool at all. Can I have some patch. Where do i get it?

Comment: Just list all drivers used in system by command
" find /sys | grep drivers.* "
and try to guess the ethernet or other device that might be used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The fish

You are calling ioctl on a filedescriptor that is representing socket. If you examine `net/socket.c` file, you will find `socket_file_ops` structure that defines `sock_ioctl` as a ioctl callback. For `SIOCETHTOOL`, this function will call `sock_do_ioctl` which in turn (after checking that this particular socket type (AF_INET - af_inet.c, inet_ioctl function) does not handle this ioctl by itself) will call `dev_ioctl` which can handle `SIOCETHTOOL` by calling `dev_ethtool`. If your driver defines `ethtool_ops`, this should be supported.

Now finding which device driver supports your network interface is another thing but this isn't really hard. One way to do this is to use sysfs, just check what is this symlink pointing to (substituting `eth0` with your interface name):

```
readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/module
../../../../module/e1000e
```

So my ethernet card is driven by module `e1000e`.

### The fishing rod

Now I found this out by reading the code. I do know something about kernel code so I knew where I should look. If I wouldn't, however, there's other way to find this out - tracing. Now I'm not sure if all this works on 2.6.32, but at least I tested this on kernel 3.2 (which isn't that much different). I won't go into details on how to configure your kernel to have all those functionalities. Ubuntu 12.04 has all that is needed and if you're interested google for `ftrace`:

You need `debugfs` mounted and a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
DEBUGFS=`/sys/kernel/debug/`
echo $$ > $DEBUGFS/tracing/set_ftrace_pid
echo function > $DEBUGFS/tracing/current_tracer
exec $*
```

This script will set `ftrace` to only care about current PID, enable function tracer and exec the command specified as an argument (without forking as that would change the PID).

Now, if your application that is using this ioctl is `/tmp/a.out`, you can call:

```
~/bin/ftraceme.sh /tmp/a.out
echo -n "" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/current_tracer
grep ioctl /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
```

In my case, I've got:

```
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750675: sys_ioctl <-system_call_fastpath    (1)
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750675: fget_light <-sys_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750675: security_file_ioctl <-sys_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750676: cap_file_ioctl <-security_file_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750676: do_vfs_ioctl <-sys_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750676: sock_ioctl <-do_vfs_ioctl           (2)
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750677: sock_do_ioctl <-sock_ioctl          (3)
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750677: inet_ioctl <-sock_do_ioctl          (4)
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750677: udp_ioctl <-inet_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750678: dev_ioctl <-sock_do_ioctl           (5)
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750678: _cond_resched <-dev_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750679: dev_load <-dev_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750680: rtnl_lock <-dev_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750680: dev_ethtool <-dev_ioctl             (6)
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750684: rtnl_unlock <-dev_ioctl
<...>-11009 [007] 596251.750685: _cond_resched <-dev_ioctl
```

Which proves what I wrote above.

Comment: Your answer is very convincing, except that its not (yet) working for me. I mounted the sysfs, and run the command `readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/module`. The output is nothing at all. In fact the content of folder `readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/` is a file `bind`, then `uevent` , `unbind` and 3 symlinks `e0082200.ucc -> ../../../../devices/e0080000.qe/e0082200.ucc` , `e0083400.ucc -> ../../../../devices/e0080000.qe/e0083400.ucc` , `e0083600.ucc -> ../../../../devices/e0080000.qe/e0083600.ucc`

Comment: So there is not a file named `module` over there. Is this some different scenrio or what, the same thing works for me on my system on ubuntu 12.04. I am digging into `ftrace`. Thnx for that.

Comment: @mdsingh: Maybe your driver is not compiled as a module but is compiled in. It seems to be a PCI card, try using `lspci -v` to find out the driver. You can also get back one step and see what is `/sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver` linking to.

Comment: output of `lspci -v` is `00:00.0 Class 0604: Unknown device 1957:0061 (rev 21)
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable)
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00000000-00000fff
        Memory behind bridge: 80000000-8fffffff
        Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [4c] Express Root Port (Slot-) IRQ 0
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting`

Comment: output of `ls -l /sys/class/net/eth0/device` is `driver -> ../../../bus/of_platform/drivers/ucc_geth` with other long listings. What do you make out of it

Comment: @mdsingh: Ech does embedded systems. [ucc_geth](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/freescale/ucc_geth.c) is your driver.

Comment: Though so, okay, pretty cool !!! Thnx a ton :) Have never got such clear answers @Krzysztof Adamski